# Variable declaration shortcut outside of function

Tags: go

Coming from a background in Java and C# I am very pleased with the brevity of Golang's ability to use the shortcut method for variable declaration for private variables within functions, which allows me to write:

```
x := 1.5
```

It reminds me of duck typing in a dynamic language such as Python. However, in declaring global variables outside of the scope of a function you still need to use the more verbose syntax of:

```
var x float64 = 1.5
```

I'm just wondering why the shortcut method works for private variables and not globals? I know that the designers of the language are quite experienced so I'm assuming that this isn't reflective of a feature overlooked. Is there a technical reason why this kind of type inference (and I realize that the := shortcut is not the same as proper type inference) wouldn't work at the global scope? It just seems somewhat inconsistent in terms of the design, and as an inexperienced Gopher I must admit to being thrown off by this on a couple of occasions. On the whole however I'm really enjoying Go.

Comment: Because all package-level declarations start with a keyword (import, type, func, const, var, etc).

Comment: @divan You're right it seems to be along the same lines as my question. I searched before asking it but somehow didn't run across this. Apologies for the duplication. I'd delete my question but there are now answers so I don't think it's possible. I'm sure it'll be marked as a duplicate shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Ian's answer in this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/qTZemuGDV6o/IyCwXPJsUFIJ

> At the top level, every declaration begins with a keyword. This
>   simplifies parsing.

Comment: And [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/OqYL9lgsPQ4/udp0nPHPZTgJ) for some additional info:

At the top level, var (or const or type or func) is necessary: each item must be introduced by a keyword for ur-syntactic reasons related to recognizing statement boundaries.  With the later changes involving semicolons, it became possible, I believe, to eliminate the need for var in some cases, but since const, type, and func must remain, it's not a compelling argument.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to specify type in many cases.

```
var x = 1.5
```

should work fine. It's probably as short as it can get and it's not much longer than local variable shortcut.
So there is a shortcut for global.

As to why `:=` can't be used, I would guess that calling out `var` makes code structure more consistent as other global constructs start with a keyword - `func`, `const`, `import`, `type`.